# Azure DevOps group rule to add everyone as readers

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to allow all members of the organization in Azure DevOps to view all projects (become Readers).

I tried to set up a group rule on the organization settings page.

Group: "Project Collection Valid Users"
Access level: Stakeholder
Projects: Selected them all, and picked Readers for each one.

After that I clicked on Add.

Now, when I try to view the rule I just made with "Manage rule", the project settings have been cleared.
If I select the projects again, and pick Readers, then save, the same thing happens.
Why do the settings disappear?

Also, if I do "Re-evaluate Rules", it runs for a bit. But none of the existing users regardless of their Access level have gotten Reader access to any project.
However, using "Manage user" -> Group rules, the group rule is listed.
So the group rule is applied but the project settings are not working for some reason? How do I fix this?

Comment: Glad to know that you found the reason. Please mark your answer which will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose a different group from AD instead of "Project Collection Valid Users" and now it seems to work as expected.

Using "Project Collection Valid Users" in this context seems to bring some bugs or unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same behaviour using the group 'Readers' or 'Project-Scoped Users'.

It seems like the default security groups can't be used for rules: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#default-security-groups

So you have to create a new group...